# Why mysql service is not accessible?

Tags: mysql, docker, flask, docker-compose

The service name is not resolving to the host of mysql during establishing connection.
The service name is mysqldb but when I use it as the host while connecting to the database, it generates error.

***Solved:* The problem was with startup of containers. The flask container did not wait for the mysql container to be *ready*. That is why it exited early. I did a quick fix by using restart policy for flask container on failure.**

The docker-compose.yml file:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3333:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
  flask-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
```

Using mysql.connector

```
mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="mysqldb", user="root",password="root", database="myapp", port="3306")
```

This is the error I'm getting

```
flask-app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 509, in open_connection
flask-app_1  |     self.sock.connect(sockaddr)
flask-app_1  | ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused
flask-app_1  | 
flask-app_1  | During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
flask-app_1  | 
flask-app_1  | Traceback (most recent call last):
flask-app_1  |   File "app.py", line 10, in <module>
flask-app_1  |     mydb = mysql.connector.connect(host="mysqldb", user="root",password="root", database="myapp", port="3306")
flask-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/__init__.py", line 179, in connect
flask-app_1  |     return MySQLConnection(*args, **kwargs)
flask-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 95, in __init__
flask-app_1  |     self.connect(**kwargs)
flask-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/abstracts.py", line 716, in connect
flask-app_1  |     self._open_connection()
flask-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/connection.py", line 206, in _open_connection
flask-app_1  |     self._socket.open_connection()
flask-app_1  |   File "/usr/local/lib/python3.7/site-packages/mysql/connector/network.py", line 512, in open_connection
flask-app_1  |     errno=2003, values=(self.get_address(), _strioerror(err)))
flask-app_1  | mysql.connector.errors.InterfaceError: 2003: Can't connect to MySQL server on 'mysqldb:3306' (111 Connection refused)
flaskapp_flask-app_1 exited with code 1
```

Here is the docker-compose ps

```
Name                     Command             State                 Ports              
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
flaskapp_flask-app_1   python3 app.py                Up      0.0.0.0:5000->5000/tcp           
flaskapp_mysqldb_1     docker-entrypoint.sh mysqld   Up      0.0.0.0:3333->3306/tcp, 33060/tcp
```

docker network ls

```
NETWORK ID          NAME                DRIVER              SCOPE
509b1e597bc4        bridge              bridge              local
b841295e0dc6        flaskapp_default    bridge              local
2cd96006df91        host                host                local
260025d73006        none                null                local
```

Comment: you need to setup `networks` or `links` to be able to call containers service names

Comment: Shouldn't you use port `3333` to connect to your database?

Comment: doesn't docker-compose place both the containers in same network i.e bridged?

Comment: The port 3333 is for accessing the DB from localhost.

Comment: can you access your database from local?

Comment: also try restarting flask-app only after ther error by command like `docker-compose restart flask-app`

Comment: I can access the DB from localhost

Comment: Can you paste `docker-compose ps`, `docker network ls`?

Comment: The other canonical cause of this is the Flask application starting immediately, but the database needing a minute or so to fully start up; re-running `docker-compose up` or following @GaneshKarewad's suggestion to restart the one container may or may not help.

Comment: @GaneshKarewad I've pasted the n/w and compose ps. just so you know i was restarting flask app on failure so that's why it's showing up the o/p otherwise it halts

Comment: @DavidMaze That is also the case. The flask app exited before starting the mysql container so i waited and restarted the container so the new error is        
```  mysql.connector.errors.NotSupportedError: Authentication plugin 'caching_sha2_password' is not supported
```

Comment: @DavidMaze Yup solved the main issue. It was as you said the flask app did not wait for the mysql to start properly and hence exited. So i waited for a bit and manually started the flask container and now it's working just as it should have. Now the main issue is how do i make the flask container to wait until mysql container starts properly

Answer (score 0):

As someone stated in your comments, you need to configure `networks` or `links`.

Here is an example of how you can configure networks using your docker-compose.yml example:

```
version: '3.7'
services:
  mysqldb:
    image: mysql:latest
    environment:
        MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD: root
        MYSQL_DATABASE: myapp
        MYSQL_PASSWORD: root
    ports:
      - "3333:3306"
    volumes:
      - ./db:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/:ro
    networks:
      - mynetwork
  flask-app:
    build: .
    ports:
      - "5000:5000"
    depends_on:
      - mysqldb
    networks:
      - mynetwork
networks: 
  mynetwork:
```

Both `mysqldb` and `flask-app` will join the `mynetwork` network.

I usually over-test so i'd also `docker-compose exec flask-app bash` and run a `ping mysql` command (assuming ping is installed) to ensure you have network connectivity between your two containers.

Also, while I mentioned `links`, you should avoid using it as it is a deprecated feature and may be removed in a future docker-compose version.

Comment: The problem was not with networking but the startup of containers. But doesn't creating docker-compose start the services in same n/w. So why do I need to create new n/w.

Comment: I think you are right about the default network that should get created. But I think the startup of containers is failing because your entrypoint is failing which is the connection refused error. I'd then start with the mysql container and run a `netstat -tulpn` within to see if the port is open. It could be that your mysql is failing? Can you connect from your host machine on port 3333?

Answer (score -1):

your mysql service has a listener on Port 3333.

PORTS syntax:  HOST:CONTAINER (https://docs.docker.com/compose/compose-file/)

In your flask app you tried to connect to port 3306. But in your default docker network i assume is no mysqldb listening in port 3306.

FYI:
Try netstat -tulpn in your container to see all listeners.